# Prevent "bubbling"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure this is really bubbling, I will explain.

I have this:

```
<div>
  <div>
    text here
  </div>
</div>
```

How to bind an on click event so that it will affect only the enclosed div? If I set it like this:

```
jQuery('div').bind('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).css('background','blue');
});
```

it makes blue all the divs. If I add false as the third argument(prevent bubbling) to the bind function it does nothing.

How can I solved this?

Comment: Have you tried [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation) in your handler? If there are no ambient capturing handlers, that should be fine, as it prevent the event from reaching any ambient bubbling handlers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Add `event.stopPropagation();` inside the hander.

(It might be better, though, to assign an ID or class to the nested DIV so you can be sure it's the only one affected.)

Comment: it's the best approach if you're not sure how many divs you have

Answer (score 4):

You should really use identifiers like IDs or classes, but for your example, you could do this:

```
jQuery('div > div').bind('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).css('background','blue');
});
```

...which will bind the handler to any `div` that is a direct descendant of another `div`.

So either make your initial selection specific to the element(s) you want to affect, or use event delegation, placing a handler on an ancestor, and testing for the element you want.

**Delegation example:** http://jsbin.com/ehemac/edit#javascript,live

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="outer">
      <div>
        text here
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
      <div>
        text here
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
jQuery('#container').delegate( '.outer > div', 'click', function() {
    jQuery(this).css('background','blue');
});
```

This uses the [`delegate()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method  that places a handler on the ancestor with the ID `#container`.

The first argument to `.delegate()` is a selector. Any elements that are clicked inside `#container` will have that selector compared against the element clicked. If the selector matches, the handler will be invoked.

Comment: Again this doesn't work if your div is nested more than element down (eg `<div><div><div>here</div></div></div>`), which would set the background always on the second element (http://jsbin.com/ehemac/2/edit).

Comment: From my answer: *"You should really use identifiers like IDs or classes...but for your example, you could do..."*. I didn't say the first code example would work in other situations. My main answer is to properly identify elements on the page.

Comment: And it's funny, normally I'm answering what the person is asking, not what they're wanting.  Here, the roles are reversed.  Though, I still do firmly believe there should either be an element id, or classname to work on.

Comment: Yeah, it's always a judgement call when we see a question that says *"I have this:"* `<div><div>text here</div></div>`. In the back of my mind I'm thinking... really? That's your markup? ;)

Comment: Hahaha... I would buy you a drink for making me laugh

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/WzSkj/

### Targeting the last descendant

#### Credit to [Patrick DW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113716/user113716):

```
jQuery('div:not(:has(div))').bind('click', function() {
   jQuery(this).css('background','blue');
});
```

This should be all you need as it will look at all `div` and find those that don't have child divs (thus, they will be the last descendant of that element type.  You could further filter this to make sure they have a parent that is a div, if you wanted to exclude those `div`s that are standalone.

---

#### Older Answer:

This is not by any means meant to be a complete/robust plugin.  It serves as only an example of how to target the last element in a chain.  See the revision history for a way to do it w/o the plugin.  This should be modified if you wish to use it for production.

#### Plugin:

```
(function($){
   $.fn.lastDescendant = function(el){
      var found = jQuery(el + ':first').siblings(el).andSelf();
      var prev, curr;
      var stack = this;
      for (var i=0,n=found.length; i<n; i++){
         curr = found.eq(i).find(el);
         while (curr.length){
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.find(el);
         }         
         stack = stack.add(prev);
      }
      return stack;
   };
})( jQuery );
```

#### Example Call:

```
jQuery.fn.lastDescendant('div')
      .click(function(){
         jQuery(this).css("background","#09c");
      });
```

***Note:***

- *this will not select the first (ancestor) element.  If you want to select that as well, you could wrap the whole thing in a new `div`, and then do the above.*
- *if I were to make this a production plugin, I would include checking the parameter, and allow you to be able to pass in an object and a starting point (so that siblings are not selected)*

Comment: +1 for the plugin, although we can get identical behavior (except for your *"this should't work"* div) by doing `$('div:not(:has(div))')`, or more generically `$('*:not(:has(*))')` to target any element that doesn't have a nested element.

Comment: Nice patrick, that would work, and may be a much better option. I'm trying to update it for passing in strings, objects, and jQuery objects.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this just use a more specific selector

```
jQuery('div > div').bind('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).css('background','blue');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve it would be to give your inner `div` an identifiable feature such as a class, e.g., `<div class="inner"></div>`.

Alternatively, change your selector:

```
$('div > div').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'blue');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try giving the inner div an id tag and refer to it...

```
<div><div id=foo>text goes here</div></div>


...

$('#foo').bind('click', function() {
  $(this).css('background','blue');
});
```

HTH
-- Joe