# Do child element register a click event with a parent element in jquery?

Tags: jquery

if I've got a floating message box and i'm wondering if clicking paragraph text within that box will also register a click on it's parent element in jQuery or if i have to add click listeners for the child elements as well.

**update:** here's the basic layout:

```
<div id='msgbox'>
<p>This is the <span>message</span></p>
</div>
```

Now if i click the text in the `<p>` or in the `<span>` will it still trigger as a click on `$('#msgbox')` ?

**update 2:** Can I stop this behavior??

**update 3:** here's the fiddle i've got going: http://jsfiddle.net/MZtbY/ - now is there a way to stop propagation after it reaches a certain level? so clicking the `<p>` would be ok, but clicking the `<span>` would  do nothing? - sort of like `$('#msgbox :nth-child').click(function(e) {e.stopPropagation();});`

Comment: here's a second thought: is there a way to prevent it if the text inside is dynamic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's an example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zCDqJ/1/)

```
$('#msgbox').click(function(evt){ 
   alert("click on msgbox: "+evt.target); 
});

// stop bubbling for the span only.
$('#msgbox span').click(function(evt) { 
   evt.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Note that clicking on the #msgbox `<div>` (that's the red box in the jsFiddle), or on the first section of the paragraph text will both trigger the event handler on #msgbox; but clicking on the text inside the `<span>` will not.  This is because we've applied a handler directly to the span, and called `stopPropagation()` on that event to prevent the normal bubbling action.

---

**Update**: [here's an update to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MZtbY/5/) that shows the same thing.

Comment: cool. what if the contents are dynamic, and I don't know that it's a `<span>` that's inside it?

Comment: Then give it an id, or classname, or select it some other way.  It doesn't matter how you make the jquery object - once you have it, bind a click handler, and use stopPropagation.  If you're adding the dynamic content *after* you bind your events, then you'll need to use [`.live('click', function(evt){...}; )`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of [`.click(function(evt){...})`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Comment: ok that makes sense, but i'm not certain of how i can select "All Great-Grandchildren" is there a jquery function for that? - on second thought, i think i'm getting away from the original question a bit, so i'll do some digging on this myself. - Thanks for the help @Lee

Comment: "All great-grandchildren of #msgbox":  `$('#msgbox > * > * > *')`.  Check out the [jQuery Selectors doc page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for details about all the different jQuery selectors that are available.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stop it from bubbling use

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: awesome. is there a way to stop propagation after you reach a certain level? so clicking the `<p>` would be ok, but clicking the `<span>` would do nothing?

Answer (score 2):

By default, events "Bubble" in JavaScript. They fire at the level you trigger and then one at a time through parent elements.

For more on event bubbling: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

To stop it: [Prevent "bubbling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208317/prevent-bubbling)

Comment: great thanks for the tip, and the link.